# Sleuth baggage is not working in integration test

Tags: spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-sleuth

Please hint me how to get Sleuth Baggage working in integration test.
It works as expected when test pass mock HTTP request but does not work when test calls service directly.
My application is (Spring Boot 2.5.4, Spring Cloud 2020.0.3):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    BaggageField myBaggageField() {
        return BaggageField.create("my-field-name");
    }

    @RestController
    static class MyController {

        @AutowiredMyService myService;

        @GetMapping
        String callService() {
            return myService.updateAndGet();
        }
    }

    @Service
    static class MyService {

        @Autowired BaggageField baggageField;

        public String updateAndGet() {
            baggageField.updateValue("value");
            return baggageField.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

application.yml:
`spring.sleuth.baggage.remote-fields: my-field-name`

test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testBaggageByService() {
        assertThat(myService.updateAndGet()).isEqualTo("value");         // FAILS
    }

    @Test
    void testBaggageByController() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(content().string("value"));  // PASS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the docs about flush and update option in Brave - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#features-baggage

Set this up and try again

```
// configuration
@Bean
BaggageField countryCodeField() {
    return BaggageField.create("my-field-name");
}

@Bean
ScopeDecorator mdcScopeDecorator() {
    return MDCScopeDecorator.newBuilder()
            .clear()
            .add(SingleCorrelationField.newBuilder(countryCodeField())
                    .flushOnUpdate()
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

EDIT:

In your comment you state:

> Well, Sleuth instrumentation is a Servlet Filter, but additionaly there are many other instrumentations, for example for message listener, for quartz scheduler etc. I simply guess there should be also instrumentation for integration test as well

There is no such integration and I don't see any point in having one. You have to start a span yourself, manually in your test and put it in scope. You can find an example here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v3.0.3/tests/common/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/circuitbreaker/CircuitBreakerIntegrationTests.java#L55-L71

```
@Autowired
Tracer tracer;

@Autowired
CircuitBreakerFactory factory;

@Test
public void should_pass_tracing_information_when_using_circuit_breaker() {
    // given
    Tracer tracer = this.tracer;
    ScopedSpan scopedSpan = null;
    try {
        scopedSpan = tracer.startScopedSpan("start");
        // when
        Span span = this.factory.create("name").run(tracer::currentSpan);

        BDDAssertions.then(span).isNotNull();
        BDDAssertions.then(scopedSpan.context().traceId()).isEqualTo(span.context().traceId());
    }
    finally {
        scopedSpan.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcin, it does not help. You refer to documentation how to automatically pass updated baggage to MDC. But my problem is that there is no tracing context in my integration test when I call service method directly and for that reason my baggage is effectively `/dev/null`.

Comment: Now is fine, but I thought there is more handy solution. Actually I migrate from home-grown tracing to Sleuth and I'm looking for a solution to reduce integration test impact to minimum

Answer (score 0):

This is expected since you are just calling the method of the controller. The Sleuth instrumentation is basically a Servlet Filter which is not called in the first test but it is used in the second because it simulates receiving a real request (also, it is not really an integration test).

You can [create a span manually](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-creating-and-ending-spans) and [set the baggage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-baggage) to simulate the behavior you are skipping.

Comment: Well, Sleuth instrumentation is a Servlet Filter, but additionaly there are many other instrumentations, for example for message listener, for quartz scheduler etc. I simply guess there should be also instrumentation for integration test as well

Comment: You can use JUnit `@BeforeEach`/`@AfterEach` to start/stop spans but I would suggest using MockMVC to test this. I'm also curious what are you trying to really achieve (I'm a Spring Cloud Sleuth maintainer and curious about your use-case).

Comment: Indeed, in this simple demo case I can test my feature with MockMVC. But usually MockMVC tests are less readable than service method tests. I like to have one MockMVC test to verify microservice is working and many service method test to verify all cases. But I have also service method scheduler method - Sleuth instruments scheduler (quartz) executor but in test I call service method. You are right that I can manage span manually in `@BeforeEach/@AfterEach` but I would like to have JUnit `Extension` which makes it automatically - it seems now I have to implement it own.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason starting a span should be reused among many tests, that is my JUnit 5 extension:

```
public class SleuthExtension implements BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    private static final Namespace SPAN_STORE_KEY = Namespace.create(SleuthExtension.class.getName());
    private static final String SPAN_KEY = "test span";

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        Tracer tracer = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context)
            .getBean(Tracer.class);
        ScopedSpan span = tracer.startScopedSpan("span for " + context.getDisplayName());

        context.getStore(SPAN_STORE_KEY)
            .put(SPAN_KEY, span);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        context.getStore(SPAN_STORE_KEY)
            .remove(SPAN_KEY, ScopedSpan.class)
            .end();
    }

}
```