# BaggageField updateValue method returns false in jUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-cloud-sleuth

EDIT: One problem was that `Tracing.current()` was null. I fixed this with the new `@BeforeEach` instead of the old `@BeforeTestMethod`:

```
Tracer tracer;

@BeforeEach
void init() {
    tracer = Tracing.newBuilder().build().tracer();
    TraceContext ctx = TraceContext.newBuilder().traceId(17).spanId(17).build();
    Span span = tracer.toSpan(ctx);
    tracer.withSpanInScope(span);
}
```

Yet, updateValue still doesn't work as there are no extras in the context, so nothing to update...

---

Following the ideas like in [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080641/sleuth-baggage-is-not-working-in-integration-test), I'm trying to use `BaggageField`s in one of my tests. All the objects are not null, but `updateValue` returns false and the test fails with `BaggageTest.baggageTest:40 expected: <hello> but was: <null>`. As said, I have no idea why the `updateValue` method is not working.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import brave.baggage.BaggageField;
import brave.baggage.CorrelationScopeConfig;
import brave.context.slf4j.MDCScopeDecorator;
import brave.propagation.CurrentTraceContext;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.ScopedSpan;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.event.annotation.BeforeTestMethod;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class BaggageTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;
    
    @BeforeTestMethod
    void init() {
        Tracer tracer = context.getBean(Tracer.class);
        ScopedSpan span = tracer.startScopedSpan("test");
    }

    @Test
    void baggageTest() {
        BaggageField fooBar = context.getBean("fooBar", BaggageField.class);
        log.info("updateValue {}", fooBar.updateValue("hello"));
        assertEquals("hello", fooBar.getValue());
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        private BaggageField findOrCreate(String name) {
            BaggageField field = BaggageField.getByName(name);
            if (field == null) {
                field = BaggageField.create(name);
            }
            return field;
        }

        @Bean("fooBar")
        BaggageField fooBar() {
            return findOrCreate("fooBar");
        }

        @Bean
        CurrentTraceContext.ScopeDecorator mdcScopeDecorator() {
            return MDCScopeDecorator.newBuilder()
                .clear()
                .add(CorrelationScopeConfig.SingleCorrelationField.newBuilder(fooBar())
                    .flushOnUpdate()
                    .build())
                .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to manually build the `TraceContext`, using the following snippet, being careful that `BaggageFields` is `brave.`**internal**`.baggage.BaggageFields`.

```
@Autowired
BaggageField field;

Tracer tracer;

@BeforeEach
void init() {
    tracer = Tracing.newBuilder().build().tracer();
    ArrayList<BaggageField> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(field);
    TraceContext ctx = TraceContext.newBuilder()
        .addExtra(BaggageFields.newFactory(list,2).create())
        .traceId(17).spanId(17).build();
    Span span = tracer.toSpan(ctx);
    tracer.withSpanInScope(span);
}
```